# Postgres Query to get all elements inside a time period, and the element right

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine I have the following table:

```
|----|------------|--------------|---------------|
|id  | time       | is_installed | software_name |
|----|------------|--------------|---------------| 
| 1. | 2024-02-28 | true.        | one           |
| 2. | 2024-02-28 | false.       | two           |
| 3. | 2024-03-02 | false.       | one           |
| 4. | 2024-03-05 | true.        | one           |
| 5. | 2024-03-01 | true.        | two           |
| 6. | 2024-02-01 | true.        | three         |
| 7. | 2024-03-01 | false.       | three         |
```

This table contains the time entries in which a software was installed or uninstalled.

Imagine that I want to get, for a determined time period, the entries in which the software was installed.

As an example, if I want to retrieve what software was installed during March 2024, so therefore I need to retrieve the following entries:

```
|----|------------|--------------|---------------|
|id  | time       | is_installed | software_name |
|----|------------|--------------|---------------| 
| 1. | 2024-02-28 | true.        | one           |
| 3. | 2024-03-02 | false.       | one           |
| 4. | 2024-03-05 | true.        | one           |
| 5. | 2024-03-01 | true.        | two           |
```

Since the software **one** was installed between (2024-02-28, 2024-03-02), and (2024-03-05,...), and the software **two** was installed in 2024-03-01. Software **three** is not applicable since it was uninstalled before the time started, and never installed again.

I would be able to query the entries during that time period, if I understand postgres have something like:

```
select *
from my_table
where time between '2024-03-01' and '2024-03-30'
```

but that would not give me the entries in which a software is installed before the "starting time", and not uninstalled before the "starting time".

How can I query the entries in which the software is installed before the starting time, and not uninstalled? So, to follow the example, how could I get the entry with id 1, but not the entry with id 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the installed date range for each record of the table. I assume that if no "install" record precedes a "uninstall" one than the software has been installed on the UNIX epoch day and if no "uninstall" record follows an "install" one then the software will be uninstalled in infinity.

```sql
CREATE temporary TABLE the_table (
  id integer,
  edate date,
  is_installed boolean,
  software_name text
);

INSERT INTO the_table
VALUES
  (1, '2024-02-28', 'true', 'one'),
  (2, '2024-02-28', 'false', 'two'),
  (3, '2024-03-02', 'false', 'one'),
  (4, '2024-03-05', 'true', 'one'),
  (5, '2024-03-01', 'true', 'two'),
  (6, '2024-02-01', 'true', 'three'),
  (7, '2024-03-01', 'false', 'three');
  
SELECT *, case
   when not is_installed then daterange(coalesce(lag(edate) over w, 'epoch'), edate)
   when is_installed then daterange(edate, coalesce(lead(edate) over w, 'infinity'))
  end as installed_daterange
from the_table
window w as (partition by software_name order by edate);
```

| id | edate | is_installed | software_name | installed_daterange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-28 | true | one | [2024-02-28,2024-03-02) |
| 3 | 2024-03-02 | false | one | [2024-02-28,2024-03-02) |
| 4 | 2024-03-05 | true | one | [2024-03-05,infinity) |
| 6 | 2024-02-01 | true | three | [2024-02-01,2024-03-01) |
| 7 | 2024-03-01 | false | three | [2024-02-01,2024-03-01) |
| 2 | 2024-02-28 | false | two | [1970-01-01,2024-02-28) |
| 5 | 2024-03-01 | true | two | [2024-03-01,infinity) |

Then use the above query as a CTE and select from it filtering that `installed_daterange` overlaps `[2024-03-01,2024-04-01)`

```sql
with t as (
 select *, case
   when not is_installed then daterange(coalesce(lag(edate) over w, 'epoch'), edate)
   when is_installed then daterange(edate, coalesce(lead(edate) over w, 'infinity'))
  end as installed_daterange
 from the_table
 window w as (partition by software_name order by edate)
)   
select * from t
where installed_daterange && daterange('2024-03-01', '2024-04-01');
```

| id | edate | is_installed | software_name | installed_daterange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-28 | true | one | [2024-02-28,2024-03-02) |
| 3 | 2024-03-02 | false | one | [2024-02-28,2024-03-02) |
| 4 | 2024-03-05 | true | one | [2024-03-05,infinity) |
| 5 | 2024-03-01 | true | two | [2024-03-01,infinity) |

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eLWF9eFLNbbrjaq7XcGcHg/0)

Comment: Hi Stefanov.sm, thanks for your answer. I am still triyng to digest it!